# When vs On which is more proper?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

> ***On*** reaching the airport, Tom found that he had left his bag in his
>   home.
>
> ***When*** reaching the airport Tom found that he had left his bag in his home.
>
> Which sentence is correct?
>
> What is the difference between them?

Edit: It is a question in a text book and I have no idea about the difference.

My guess is that the sentence with “on” equals “on reaching that point” which means immediately when he arrived that he found that he had left his bags.

Comment: It is a good idea to mention what research you did to solve the problem. For example, tell us why you are choosing between "on" and "when" (and not "after"), tell us if you saw any similar sentences with "when" (if yes, provide examples), tell us if you searched google for the phrases "on reaching" and "when reaching". Also, the two sentences are not identical - one has "had" and the other does not. One has "bag" and the other has "bags".

Comment: I have edited the post, there were some  errors in writing with “had” and “bags”.